# Continuity between 2 iPhones (of which 1 not connected to Cellular / without SIM)

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, messages, continuity

I recently bought an iPhone 6S, but my trusty iPhone 5S is still in good condition so I figured I would keep it around for use at home. I'm currently using the iPhone 5S as "fixed line replacement" with a VoIP app, as an Apple TV remote, and some other purposes (basically like an iPod Touch), so there is no SIM card in the phone and it's in Airplane Mode with WiFi on (I'm thinking of putting an inactive SIM in there to get rid of a few error messages though).

Recently I noticed that when someone calls me on my iPhone 6S, after a few seconds the call also comes through on the iPhone 5S thanks to Continuity, which is very handy. The thing is, it doesn't work in the other direction seeing as this is an actual iPhone, it will complain (both in Messaging and Phone apps) that either there is no SIM installed, or that Airplane Mode should be disabled.

Is there a way that I can get the iPhone 5S (without SIM, in Airplane Mode with WiFi on) to behave like an iPad and use the cellular connectivity of my iPhone 6S via Continuity over WiFi, so that I can also make cellular calls and send/receive SMS/MMS messages on the 5S (WiFi only) when the iPhone 6S is nearby? Or are the incoming calls really the only possibility in this case?

Comment: On my various iPad - when they have bluetooth and WiFi on, I can use the contacts app to tap a phone icon next to a contact's phone number and the iPad initiates a call via handoff/continuity using the iPhone 6. Are you dialing via that method? Can you upload an image of the error message you are getting? It might be coded into the software to not hand off calls from any device that has a normal phone (like the iPhone 5) so that will let us know if a jailbreak to change iOS on the phone to work like an iPad is needed or if it's just a matter of getting the settings and steps right for you.

Comment: The error I'm getting in Airplane Mode is "You must disable Airplane Mode to make a call", and when I disable it, for a split second it tries to place the call but it's instantly cancelled, showing a "No SIM Card Installed" error. This happens when I try to call using the Phone app. In the contacts app, the "phone icon" isn't shown next to the contact name in the main view as it is on the iPad with continuity. Instead, you have to go into the contact details, where you can select message or call, but when trying to call, the aforementioned errors pop up again.

Comment: It appears that indeed one would have to convince the iPhone that it's not in fact an iPhone but an iPad or iPod Touch. Too bad there is no setting to configure it to operate as such, that would negate the need to enable airplane mode and would allow for full integration with continuity, while allowing it to fall back to full-fledged iPhone operation when desired.